# Is it possible and if so, how to bind font glyphs to all keyboard ALT+sign button combinations?

Tags: unicode, fonts, fontforge

I'm trying to create runic style font without meaning in any language, using FontForge.
I want it to have three to four slighty different base looks per glyph, with an option to modify them with kerning.

Is possible to assign all or part of keyboard glyphs buttons (eg.: q, w, e, t, r, ..., 1, 2, 3, ... , [, ], , ;, ', ...) to work in most text editors for keyboard combinations:

- button
- SHIFT + button
- ALT + button
- ALT + SHIFT + button

First and second can be done with just auto generated unicode versions in FontForge.
For third and fourth i have only few symbols working in my computer (Polish language) ę€óąśłńćźżĘÓĄŚŁŻŹĆŃ, so i can add their equivalents to font.

Is somewhere list of unicode numbers matching others ALT+keyboard glyph combinations?
Is needed to do something more to do like defining font language or application/system language to make it work?
Or another approach is possible to take?

Comment: Fonts don't know, let alone care, about keyboard modifiers. They only care about the character set you're implementing. Shift, Alt, Control, etc, don't exist as far as fonts know, that's purely a user interface software thing. You type "some combination of keys" on your keyboard, and if that yields "a sequence of byte codes" (because Alt+[something] combinations etc almost never do, the OS/Application handles those as operational control instructions) then _that's_ what gets passed to the font for shaping. So IF your app turns alt+key and shift+alt+key into "letters", find out which ones.

Comment: Thanks, looks like i asked wrong question and your answer helped me to clarify what i need to look for. I'll try with defining custom keyboard layout.

Answer (score 0):

Im using Windows 10 as a system and as i found correct answer to my problem is in two parts:

1. Create custom encoding in FontForge:
   a) Custom Encodings file location: $Disk$:\Users\$Username$\AppData\Roaming\FontForge\Encodings.ps. As it is in AppData folder wise is to have its backup somewhere else. Example of custom encoding:

> ```
> /fontname [
>  /1
>  /exclam
>  /2
>  /at
>  /3
>  /numbersign
>  /4
>  /dollar
>  /n
>  /nacute
>  /N
>  /Nacute
>  /m
>  /M 
> ] def
> ```

b) Use some FontForge encoding creation options:

- Save encoding to file, basing on currently active font (point a) location): Encoding->Make From Font.
- Load pre-defined encoding (last ones are custom, if exists): Encoding->Reencode.
- Remove not existing glyphs: Encoding->Compact (remove not existing glyphs)
- Remove not existing glyphs and sort them: Encoding->Reencode
- Check glyph names for FontForge in Glyph info or Glyphs editing options.

2. [Download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=102134) Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator and use it to add matching keyboard layout to font glyphs, then add it to system layouts in system settings.